# AnyLogic: Implementation of a Dirichlet distribution?

Tags: java, dirichlet, anylogic

all:

Anyone know of a way to implement draws from a Dirichlet distribution in AnyLogic?

I have three inter-related probabilities, such that p1 + p2 + p3 = 1, and I want to draw values for each of these.

I'm currently implementing this with the following code:

```
p1 = beta(10.0 * c, 10.0 * (1.0 - c));
p2 = min(beta(10.0 * a, 10.0 * (1.0 - a)), 1.0 - p1);
p3 = max(0.0, 1.0 - p2 - p2);
```

where `a` and `c` are my priors on `p1` and `p2`.

Thanks!

Comment: Forgive me as I know very little about the Dirichlet distribution, but are there any more constraints to keep in mind? Do p1 and p2 have a relationship between each other? Are you drawing p1, p2, and p3 from some other distribution, or are you doing something along the lines of p(Value1) == p1, p(Value2) == p2, and p(Value3) == p3? What exact problem are you encountering with your current implementation?

Comment: Dylan:  I'm not actually encountering PROBLEMS, per se, in the current implementation of a three-variable problem.  As the problem gets more generalized, though, a multivariate distribution such as the dirichlet would be very useful.  To answer the other questions, though, no:  p1, p2, and p3 have no relation to each other except that they sum to 1.  The expected value for each of them is calculated st the expected values sum to 1, but then I want to draw from betas with expected values of p1/p2/p3, and want those draws also to sum to 1

Comment: Ah, I see. Such statistical wizardry is beyond my expertise, I'm afraid. Seeing as no one has answered this question yet, perhaps you could ask around on the LinkedIn page then send any knowledgeable responders here. I'm sure you're not the only one who'd like to know how to implement a custom distribution from a formula, and this StackOverflow question would serve to immortalize whatever answer you receive.

Comment: Done!  Will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You may [use external Java libraries in AnyLogic](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/libraries/Adding%20External%20Jar%20Files%20and%20Java%20Classes.html). Download some Java library with implemented Dirichlet distribution, e.g. [Mallet 2](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php), and call the respective API. Also, you may copy-paste the implementation from [library source codes](https://github.com/juanmirocks/mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/types/Dirichlet.java) :)